# show dynamically changing map in messaging conversations?

Tags: android, sms

I have a requirement wherein if there is any URL in text messages i.e when we are chatting using android phone and someone send me a url , then i should display the content in the URL in a small window so that he does not have to click the URL to see the content but automatically sees the content of that webpage . Any idea on how this can be implemented because when i was looking to the messaging api , it is displaying it through cursor adapter so somehow this webview needs to be stored in db . Am i on the right track . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to detect that you have a URL. You can do this using a Regex.

Then, you need to write an xml layout for your View which includes a WebView. You can find basic usage and examples here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html.

Whether you store the messages in a db or not is up to you, depending on your needs.